# Install a program remotely in a group of windows 7 computers with admin access

Tags: windows, remote-access, remote, remote-control

I would like to know, how it will be possible to install different programs remotely to a group of computers with Windows 7 with admin permissions in all of them.

I have access to them physically, but these computers are far from my place and I would like to reduce the numbers of times that I have to go.

I thought I could use [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/), but I don't have any idea how I could execute this remotely, and also I have the problem that some of this programs that I would need to install doesn't have a package that I can use.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your programs must have standalone or unattended installers for it to work, otherwise you are left with having to use some RDP or VNC app to manually click on the installers and to navigate through the steps.

Comment: Why do you want to install programs and configure them to always have administrator permissions.  A program SHOULD NOT always have Administrator permissions.  There are very few instances where a program actually needs to be elevated.  Seems like you are trying to accomplish something that shouldn't be accomplished.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remote desktop - With other user still logged on?](https://superuser.com/questions/152435/remote-desktop-with-other-user-still-logged-on)

Comment: @Ramhound I read the question as saying “install different programs remotely to a group of computers with Windows 7, ***given that I have*** admin permissions in all of ***those computers***”. It may seem obvious, but when OPs leave out information like that, they get kicked to the curb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Arielnmz said, unless you have a silent installer, RDP is going to be your best bet.

If this is a one time need, it might be faster to use RDP anyways.  Login remotely, do the install and your done.  For logging into multiple servers, I like to use remote desktop connection manager, rather then the native RDP tool.  It lets you save connections, group them, and manage a whole host of connection settings, while giving you an easy to manage interface to use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i am trying to use RDP , but i don't manage to connect, i get my external ip and port from [here](https://myexternalip.com/) and I donwload this [program to connect](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-remote-desktop-8-0/id715768417?mt=12) from my mac to a windows 10 computer, I change the settings to allow the computer with w10 to [allow remote connections](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/remote-desktop-client-faq#specific-errors) and i keep with the same problem

Comment: @RobertoFernandez Consider asking a different question about your problem with RDP.

Comment: I manage to know the problem, the problem is that my version of Windows 10 is home, and RDP is not supported... Can someone suggest me and alternative? I don't know if teaviewer will solve my problem, i cannot no one in the other place to put all the codes for sync the computers, they can just turn it on, thanks for the help to all

Comment: Not sure if it will help as there might be client changes needed, but it looks like windows remote assistance is still enabled in windows 10 home edition.  More info can be found here https://windowsinstructed.com/enable-disable-remote-assistance-windows/